# UART communication between STM32 and Matlab

Tags: c, matlab, embedded, stm32, uart

at the beginning, I'm relatively new to the world of microcontroller programming.

I am preparing a program for stable communication between the STM32 and a PC equipped with Matlab. Currently I've managed to create a connection between Matlab and STM32 (F303RE board) but it works unstable. Communication was based on interruptions (both receiving and sending information). My code on STM32:

Main:

```
int main(void)
{

    HAL_Init();
    SystemClockConfig();
    UART2_Init();


    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, &rcvd_data, 1);

    while (1)
    {
    Print_CAN_Frame("Tx", IPC_Ligths.ID, IPC_Ligths.DLC, IPC_Ligths.CAN_Tx);
    HAL_Delay(3000);
/*
Section for handling incoming information by UART
        while((flag_UART_RX_COMPLETED && flag_UART_TX_COMPLETED) == TRUE)
        {
            parseFromUART(data_buffer);
            saveDataToFrame(canUartBuffer);
            ClearArray(data_buffer, 70);
            count = 0;
            flag_UART_RX_COMPLETED = FALSE;
            flag_UART_TX_COMPLETED = FALSE;
        }
*/
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Callbacks

```
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    if (rcvd_data == '\r') {
        data_buffer[count++] = '\r';
        flag_UART_RX_COMPLETED = TRUE;
        if (HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2, data_buffer, count) != HAL_OK)
        {
            Error_handler();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        data_buffer[count++] = rcvd_data;
    }
    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, &rcvd_data, 1);
}

void HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
        flag_UART_TX_COMPLETED = TRUE;
}
```

and interrupts hanlders:

```
void SysTick_Handler (void)
{
    HAL_IncTick();
    HAL_SYSTICK_IRQHandler();
}

void USART2_IRQHandler (void)
{

    HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart2);

}
```

The code from matlab.
Function to send data via UART (I want a nice CAN frame to show me on the serial port monitor)

```
function statusCode = CANsend(ID, DLC, BUFFER)
% Function to send CAN data by USART port to STM32. 
% Data sended by this function will be avaiable via Serial Port Monitor
% ***** PARAMETERS *****
% ID - CAN frame identifier
% DLC - CAN frame data length code
% BUFFER - CAN frame data buffer(array) in HEX - f.e. [0xAA, 0xBB]
global serialPortConfiguration
flag = true;

UARTstring = ParseDataForUART(ID,DLC,BUFFER);
writeline(serialPortConfiguration,UARTstring);
% Check until STM32 give echo for given frame (frame accepted)
while flag
    receivedData = readline(serialPortConfiguration);
    if ( char(receivedData) == UARTstring)
        flag = false;
        statusCode = "Data Send Succeded";
        disp(UARTstring);
        pause(0.1)
    else
        pause(0.1)
        writeline(serialPortConfiguration,UARTstring);
    end 
end
end
```

and function to configure communication via UART in Matlab:

```
function InitializeCommunication(portNumber,baudRate)
% Function to configure basic USART communication paramters
% portNumber: number of serial port (f.e: 'COM5', 'COM10')
% baudRate: baud rate for communication (default 115200)
% example: InitializeCommunication('COM10',115200)

global serialPortConfiguration
serialPortConfiguration = serialport(portNumber,baudRate);
configureTerminator(serialPortConfiguration,"CR");
end
```

What is this strange behavior? First of all, after sending several frames through the CANsend function in matlab (e.g. 15 - 20). the program stops into HAL_GetTick or I have UART Over-Run error. When I uncomment in the main function the part of the code responsible for handling incoming frames the program crash after sending the first message. Apart from sending data by Matlab I'm also sending data for debugging by TeraTerm and there everything seems to work much more stable (although not identical). Do you have any ideas what could be wrong? Maybe changing the approach and implementation by DMA will help?

Comment: In HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback boundary check for data_buffer array seems to be not handled.This causes undefined behavior

Comment: Delay mismatch between stm32 code and PC code seems to be the cause of UART over run error

Comment: @Babajan when I transmit data via UART every string is eneded by '\r'. This is the boudary value that I'm checking in the if condition - or I didn't understand your answer :(. I deleted delay in Matlab code and I have problems still  :/